# objective C Comparing 2 files bytewise

Tags: objective-c

This code should load 2 files and compare them byte wise and output the differences , but for some reason it outputs a difference even if the same file is used and seems to be ignoring my formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *pathA = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"original/testfile" ofType:@""];
    NSFileHandle *fileA = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:pathA];
    NSString *pathB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"updated/testfile" ofType:@""];
    NSFileHandle *fileB = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:pathB];
    unsigned long long sizeofFile = [fileA seekToEndOfFile];
    [fileA seekToFileOffset:0];
    [fileB seekToFileOffset:0];
    unsigned int fileaValue;
    unsigned int filebValue;
    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeofFile; i++) {
        [[fileA readDataOfLength:1] getBytes:&fileaValue];
        [[fileB readDataOfLength:1] getBytes:&filebValue];
        if (fileaValue != filebValue)
            NSLog(@"File A %02x File B %02x at offset %u:",fileaValue,filebValue,i);
    }
    [fileA closeFile];
    [fileB closeFile];
    }
return 0;
}
```

Example output

```
 2013-03-13 13:50:50.580 compareFile[12055:303] File A 7fce File B 5fbff9ce at offset 0:
 2013-03-13 13:50:50.581 compareFile[12055:303] File A 7ffa File B 5fbff9fa at offset 1:
```

Comment: As pointed out in trojanfoe's answer below, note the condition of the for loop! `<` and not `<=`. To debug the code I would also try printing out unsigned int values instead of hex and see if you are getting the result you are expecting, if not then clearly the bug lies somewhere other than the formatting!

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is possibly the data types you have chosen (if you want a single byte then use `uint8_t`) and almost certainly your use of `<=` in the `for` loop:

```
uint8_t fileaValue;
uint8_t filebValue;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeofFile; i++) {   // NOT <=
    [[fileA readDataOfLength:1] getBytes:&fileaValue];
    [[fileB readDataOfLength:1] getBytes:&filebValue];
    if (fileaValue != filebValue)
        NSLog(@"File A %02x File B %02x at offset %u:", (unsigned)fileaValue, (unsigned)filebValue,i);
}
```

(Note the cast in the `NSLog()` call to make that print the values correctly).

Also checking the success of the `readDataOfLength` is in order given File I/O is a common cause of error.